# Jquerymobile Loading spinner Dialog before page is Loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

In my app I have 3 pages from the first page I am sending data to server, here I want to show a Loading dialog until the send operation (posting to server) is finished and then go to page two. Doing a below but it's not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('pageshow', '#Page2' ,function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
   $.mobile.changePage('#dialog');
  }, 100); // delay above zero
});
</script>
```

**Try2**

```
<script>  
    $(document).on("pagecreate","#page", function () {
    $("#custom-li").on("click", function () {
   var orgname = $('input:text[id=name]').val();

    loadingStart();
    setTimeout(function () {
        loadingEnd();
        $.mobile.changePage('#page2');
    }, 3000);
    return false;
   });       
});
function loadingStart() {
    $.mobile.loading('show', {
        text: "loading",
        textVisible: true
    });
}
function loadingEnd() {
    $.mobile.loading("hide");
}
</script>
```

the function is firing but the spinner is missing from the dialog when I run in browser and mobile.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So is only spinner missing? In this case, maybe you don't have "images/ajax-loader.gif" at html files directory.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @Hüseyin BABAL, i don't have new question - i try to understand which kind of problem teekib has and also i made suggestion how one of possible problems can be solved.

Comment: And then, this must be a commentary answer. It would be better to write that in comment section of question. When you fully understand the case, you can post as answer

Comment: @Regent i have the ajax-loader.png in my images folder

Comment: @Hüseyin BABAL if i have opportunity to add comment, i would definitely add it as comment, not as answer. But right now i've just tried to help "as i can".

Comment: @teekib so the whole dialog is missing? Even you set well-seen theme in $.mobile.loading?

Comment: @Regent i can see a trasparent white dailog with spinning wheel missing.  an i doing correct writing that piece of code in Pagecreate method?

Comment: @teekib yes, if you see transparent white dialog, than event is fired and "loadingStart();" is called, so this part looks normally.
In such circumstances i suggest to set theme (for example, theme: 'e' in $.mobile.loading (in {} after textVisible: true)) just to see loading dialog clearly and also to recheck existence of ajax-loader.gif in correct folder (ajax-loader is in "images" folder, which is at the same level as html-files, while, for example, "icons-18-white.png" is in "images" folder, which is at the same level as jquery-mobile.css).

Comment: @teekib i've just inserted your Try2 code to my current project and it works well. What i have:
assets/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css;
assets/www/js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js;
assets/www/js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js;
assets/www/js/OnLoad.js (<- your script was inserted here);
assets/www/images/ajax-loader.gif;

Comment: @Regent i have a png image not gif..?

Comment: @Regent yeas i have the image like this www/img/ajax-loader.png  and i am using phonegap

Comment: @teekib well, i use Cordova (it's pretty much the same to PhoneGap, as you might know). But according to the question: if you have "img/ajax-loader.png", you can: 1. rename folder and file so it will  be "images/ajax-loader.gif". 2. or you can change path in JQuery Mobile styles file to your desired one.

Comment: @teekib for JQuery Mobile 1.3.2 direct link to download standard .gif file: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/images/ajax-loader.gif

Comment: @Regent  i am using jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js...samething...can continue in chatroom so that i can show my code

Comment: @teekib i actually never see chatrooms there before, but i can try. Maybe it will help to solve problem

Comment: @Regent your not yet eligible for chatroom..anyway will try and will let you know

Comment: @teekib yeah, that's the big problem. But once more: you can save http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/images/ajax-loader.gif to the "www/images/" directory or you can change JQuery Mobile styles in it's .css file

Comment: @Regent finally it is working...you were right from first..thx a lot

Comment: @teekib I'm glad that this problem is finally solved and the answer was correct